# Is it possible to put A Column in a Row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter-layout

I tried putting a column in a row. But it does not work.

Then I tried putting the row and column in the same safe area using different child properties. It does not work.

The column is supposed to be in the middle of the row.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text('Container 1'),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('Container 1'),
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Container 1'),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('Container 1'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error message is "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width."

Answer (score 0):

Try expanded widget with flex attribute, you can put the column in a row:

```
Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(flex: 1,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
        ),
        Expanded(flex: 2,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(flex:1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(flex:1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you hoangquyy. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can place `column` using a `container`

```
body: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```